# Pandoc disable figure stretching from Markdown to PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I create PDF documents from Markdown documents using the simplest `pandoc` command:

```
pandoc my.md -o my.pdf
```

The figures inside the PDF are all stretched, i.e: 100% width.

Which configuration should I give to `pandoc` to leave the figures as is without changing figure size.

Comment: Which version of `pandoc` are you using? On which OS platform?

Comment: By "stretched" you mean: they are not keeping their aspect ratio? Or are they, and they are just magnified?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle  pandoc 1.12.2.1 Kubuntu 14.04: Linux bor-asus4 3.8.0-39-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 1 20:04:50 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @KurtPfeifle they are magnified. I want the images not to be touched. I have mobile application size images, but when magnified it shows badly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot control that feature directly from Markdown.

In recent months there have been some discussions going on in the Pandoc developer + user community about how to best implement it and create an easy-to-use syntax, for example

```
![Image Caption](./path/to/image.jpg "Image Comment"){width="60%", height="150px"}
```

(**Warning:** Example only, made up on the fly and drawn out of thin air by myself -- can't remember the latest state of the discussion...) This is designed to then transfer to ***all*** the supported output formats which can contain images, not just PDF.

So this is planned to be a major new feature for the next major release of Pandoc.

---

As you may or may not know, Pandoc doesn't create the PDFs itself. It produces LaTeX and employs LaTeX technology (by default its `pdflatex` command) to convert the LaTeX to PDF (then deleting the intermediate LaTeX files).

To execute some (limited) control about how the LaTeX/PDF pages (or other outputs) look like, Pandoc uses *template* files. You can look at the exact template definitions your own Pandoc version uses for LaTeX/PDF output by running

```
pandoc -D latex
```

So if you are a LaTeX hacker (or know one), you are able to modify that or create your own template from scratch.

In the current release of Pandoc (v1.13.2.1), there is this code snippet in the LaTeX template:

```
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
```

This should keep the original image sizes if they fit into the page width, and scale them down to the page width if they don't.

If this is not the behavior you experience with your PDF output, I suspect you are an a rather old version of Pandoc.

For using your own template instead of the builtin internal one, you can add

`--template=/path/to/myown-template.latex`

to the Pandoc command line.

Comment: I believe the first part you mentioned is possible: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex#L93                                             "and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}"

Comment: @bugdayci: Sorry, I do not understand your comment *"the first part you mentioned is possible"*. Which first part? -- Also, why are you linking to that commented line 93 on GitHub, which is identical to the commented lines given in my code block?

Comment: I've got this in my template but it scales images up. How can I keep smaller images small?

Answer (score 0):

@KurtPfeifle Thanks for your help. I updated the latex to set static width and hight for the images using the tip.

In my latex template I have:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=128pt,height=192pt,keepaspectratio}
```

This works great for the mobile images. But I also have a cover page, where the cover figure is now small sized.

I tried creating 2 different latex files and combining them but the figure sizes are back to being stretched:

```
pandoc _cover_page.md -o _cover_page.tex
pandoc ... -template=mobile_images.latex -o remaining.tex
pandoc  _cover_page.tex remaining.tex -o out.pdf
```

- Is there an easy way to combine latex files whicih obey the templates in Pandoc?
- I can create 2 pdf files: cover.pdf and remaining.pdf, and combine them too. Is there an easy tool that you know?

Comment: In the end I combined them using gs: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2799/how-to-merge-several-pdf-files#answer-257170

Comment: Your TeX-creating Pandoc commands  (the first two) generate generic TeX-snippets, without any TeX preamble. Your third Pandoc command, generating a PDF, implicitly activates `--self-contained`, which in turn includes a TeX preamble. This preamble then is valid for *all* consecutive TeX code and covers both parts, `_cover_page.tex` as well as `remaining.tex`. That's why *"the figure sizes are back to being stretched"*... -- The most easy way to combined two PDFs is: `pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf cat output combined.pdf`.